# Parsing CSV to DataGrip database failed

Tags: sqlite, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I tried to add values of a csv file to a local sqlite database using DataGrip. I think it's a bug in DataGrip because the preview is correct but I don't know how to fix it.
This is the log I get:

```
2:1: assertion failure: param count (5) != value count (40960)
3:1: assertion failure: param count (5) != value count (40960)
4:1: assertion failure: param count (5) != value count (40960)
5:1: assertion failure: param count (5) != value count (40960)
...
```

The source csv looks like this in visual studio code but DataGrip seems to fix the encoding

```
globaleID;Name ohne Ort;Ort;x_WGS84;y_WGS84
de:14612:1;Bahnhof Mitte;Dresden;13723392;51055642
de:14612:3;Prager Stra�e;Dresden;13737828;51047149
de:14612:4;Altmarkt;Dresden;13738511;51050249
de:14612:5;Pirnaischer Platz;Dresden;13743999;51049481
de:14612:6;Deutsches Hygiene-Museum;Dresden;13750081;51047629
de:14612:7;Stra�burger Platz;Dresden;13754986;51046109
de:14612:8;Georg-Arnhold-Bad;Dresden;13751330;51042568
de:14612:9;D�rerstra�e;Dresden;13757914;51051920
de:14612:10;Sachsenallee;Dresden;13757375;51054603
```

This is the import window:
[image: Screenshot]

I guess it has something to do with the encoding but it seems to be a bug because the preview in DataGrip is parsed correctly

Edit: only the last line of the csv gets parsed correctly

Comment: Does the file have the appropriate line ending format for your OS? (`\r\n` for Windows, `\n` for everything else)

Comment: The answer is still wanted :) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9840

Comment: When line ending is incorrect you'll hit `7:55: actual: record separator (\n), expected: value`. So it could be something else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9840)  was fixed. If there are any further problems - file a new issue.